# How can I get the correct resolution for "Ask ubuntu" back on my Android device

Tags: support

On my android smart phone, I was able to access **"Ask ubuntu"** with my browser with a resolution specifically designed for the phone (it was perfect).  Then, I accidentally hit a small link labelled **"web"** and the result isn't pretty, in fact it's very unintuitive. It has no resemblance to the AU site at all.

I would really like to get this resolution back as I visit the AU site almost everyday and my question is, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of the page(it may be awkward to get to) there is a link labelled "Mobile". That link will set the display to the mobile interface. Also ,you could use a javascrpt console to run

```
StackExchange.switchMobile('on', '/')
```

but it will move you to the homepage. Note that this javascript cannot be run from a `javascript:` url. It must be run from a web console. Tested on Firefox 14.